# Responsive website (mobile version)

Tags: web, responsive

I have created a website from a tutorial online. It works great on a computer.
But When I use it on a mobile device, it doesn't scale up correct. I have used the correct meta tags, but still it doesn't work. 
when I minimize my browser on my PC this is how it looks:

[image]

But when I visit the website through my mobile phone, the design changes to the 'mobile version' but everything looks to small in comparison with minimized browser version. This is how it looks on the phone:

[image]

As you see, the logo scales correctly, but the rest of the content doesn't.
Any idea on how to fix this?
If you guys want my source code, just ask it and I will upload it online.
Thanks

Comment: What kinds of answers are you expecting without providing the source?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it looks normally: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrCWG.png. 
Here is the source: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8POOYHtz9ifdTdWU0JZOG54ZVk

sorry for multiple answers, I can't post more then 2 link in the same answers.